# NSURLSessionDataTask in background session

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I would like to make an empty POST request and read the response headers while my iOS app is in the background.  Looking at the documentation it explicitly states that Upload and Download tasks are supported in the background, but there are two problems:

1. I do not need to upload content, so I do not want to have to create an empty file to use.
2. I need to get the headers, so a download task doesn't provide the necessary delegate callbacks.

Which leaves me with an `NSURLSessionDataTask`, for which the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) states:

> Note: Prior to iOS 8 and OS X 10.10, data tasks are not supported in background sessions.

However, [another documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html) states under the same title (Background Transfer Considerations):

> Only upload and download tasks are supported (no data tasks).

Which documentation page is correct? Are NSURLSessionDataTasks *without* data to upload supported in background sessions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See WWDC 2014 video [What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/707/), about 49 minutes in. The bottom line is that you can perform data tasks in background sessions now, but it will only work only if the app is running. If app is suspended or terminated, it cannot perform data task, though you can convert it to a download task when it receives the response. (FWIW, I don't find it particularly useful to have a background data task that can only work while the app is still running.)

I'm not sure why you're worrying about download vs data task. It strikes me that you could just initiate a download task and then in `didFinishDownloadingToURL`, look at `downloadTask.response`.

Having said that I'm unclear what your broader intent is. If you want to ping your server (e.g. to see if data is available for download), you'd generally use background fetch for that.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a multipart upload protocol that requires me to make a HEAD or POST request to start the upload, and I want it to work even when the app is suspended.  The point is that I want to be able to put the HEAD/POST request on the NSURLSession while the app is running but even if no data service is available, and to record the response (without saving the response to a file).

Comment: When you initiate a background request, the only options for it to be performed while the the app is not active is to perform a download or upload task. So why don't you just initiate a download request, but just ignore the downloaded response body and just look at the task's `response` when the background daemon wakes your app? Frankly, I still don't understand why the web service was designed to require two different requests when uploading data (just initiate background upload request which the background daemon will start when internet connectivity is established).

Comment: The service supports resumable uploads, so you need to be able to check the current offset of the upload with HEAD requests - like this YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

Comment: Got it. So, just do download request, don't worry about the body, but look at the header and you should be good. Note, if the app is started in background to notify you of this and you then start additional request to complete the upload, I believe that network requests started from the background automatically have `discretionary` turned on.

Comment: I assume I have to delete the saved file from a download request?

Comment: No, it does this for you. If you wanted to keep it, you'd move/copy it to a new location, but if you don't need it, I don't think you need to worry about it.